# HTML Element being ignored while applying CSS on it

Tags: html, css, vue.js

I've been using Bootstrap's vue form-group in order to create input fields.
I'm trying to apply certain CSS on the 'legend' Element for the following code:

```
<fieldset id="__BVID__59" class="form-group" required="required">
<legend class="col-form-label pt-0">Login</legend>
<div tabindex="-1" role="group">
<input type="text" class="form-control">
<!----><!----><!---->
</div>
</fieldset>
```

My goal is to add required asterisks to the labels, therefore my suggestion would be:

```
.form-group[required] legend::after {
  content: '*';
  color: red;
}
```

but my CSS doesn't seem to recognise the legend element, no matter what I do or how I write it.
it's the same if I use label instead of legend.
I've tried also using nth-child(0) of fieldset (the parent) but it seems like it's just ignoring this child and nothing really happens. I thought it has something to do with the CSS configurations of the bootstrap i'm using, but also using !important doesn't seem to do anything.

any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: It seems to be working as intended-> https://jsfiddle.net/s4j0k7nL/ Can you reproduce the problem in a snippet ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Vue if you use a scoped style tag `<style scoped>` you wont be able to select subcomponents by default. To do so you need to use a [deep selector](https://vue-loader.vuejs.org/guide/scoped-css.html#deep-selectors)

```
<style scoped>
.form-group[required] ::v-deep legend::after {
  content: '*';
  color: red;
}
</style>
```

Without scoped your css should work as expected, but i don't recommend doing so as it can mess with other components and be messy to debug.

```
<style>
.form-group[required] legend::after {
  content: '*';
  color: red;
}
</style>
```